# XAMPP (Mac) Virtual host showing 403

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I keep getting Access Forbidden Error 403 when I try running my installation of XAMPP on my MAC

I am running the project outside of `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs`. It's in my `/Users/my_user_name/Projects/` directory.

Every time I try and go to my virtualhost I get a 403 error: Access forbidden.

I have edited my httpd-vhosts.conf file and I have allowed Virtual hosts in httpd.conf.

I have also set the User and Group to User my_user_name and Group Admin in httpd.conf

I even tried chmoding all my files and directory 777 but I still get Access forbidden.

I have also change Deny to Allow in the httpd-xampp.conf file in the new security settings.

The erro_log provided by XAMPP doesn't mention the 403 error I do see it in my access log  as `127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2013:14:45:20 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 1034`

I turned on errors and I am seeing this [`authz_core:error] [pid 52813] [client 127.0.0.1:57473] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:`

Not sure what else to check or try. Please help lol.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just to have the answer right here:
You can permit access by adding `Require all granted` to each `VirtualHost` in your httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# VirtualHost for my.site.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/www/my.site.com/"
    ServerName my.site.com
    <Directory "/Users/me/www/my.site.com">
        ServerSignature Off
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All

        #Order allow,deny  <- You can remove this
        #Allow from all    <- and that

        # Insert the following:
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is the right approach. Bear in mind that you must also remove all the crap sample code in the http-vhosts.conf

Comment: Can you share the path on which file I have to update this code?

Answer (score 15):

I kept having this 403 issue and could not find an answer UNTIL...

Curly (right and left) quotes where in my vhosts file.

If you see something like "xe2\x80\x9c" in your error log then this is your problem.

I opened the httpd-vhosts.conf file in a reliable editor (I used Dreamweaver) and noticed that the quotations are curly ones (left and right quotes). They need to be straight quotes. The regular text editor on my Mac would auto change any quotes I make to these curly ones and I wasn't noticing it.

Hopefully this answer will help someone.

Comment: Thank you! Been pulling my hair out on this one. Turns out that OSX's TextEdit automatically changes the ASCII quote to the right-quote on closing a string. Another reason to avoid Apple tools...

Comment: YOU SUPERSTAR !!!  I'd been trying to get virtual hosts working for hours on a Mac with no joy. I finally saw this comment (it should be " and not ” used in the http-vhosts.con file, but TextEdit changes " back to ” WITHOUT showing you it's done so!!!!) Thank you

Answer (score 7):

In my case problem was with user definition in 
**httpd.conf** for Windows:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

Changed to

```
User myusername
```

And it worked

For linux:

```
User myusername
Group sudo
```

For OSX:

```
User myusername
Group admin
```

also you might have to set permissions on folder

```
sudo chown -R yourusername /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs
```

Comment: This was not necessary. Making sure the double quotes were not curly `“”` -> `""` and lack of `require all granted` did the trick for me. I left both User and Group as `daemon` for OSX. When I even changed only the User, my normal localhost was having `403 error`s with several `require_once` lines in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I found something that actually fixed my issue at the following link. I hope this saves someone hours of pulling out their hair. lol

http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=198815&sid=35790f5d017f27c93c1fd4d260b35128

Comment: TL;DR for that link--add a `<Directory...` block with `Require all granted`, like @AvL suggests

Comment: Dead link. The relevant content should've been copied here.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I forgot to set my 'DocumentRoot' url and my 'Directory' url the same.

```
#dl local
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dl.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myuser/dl_live"               <<< ----- This URL has to match
    <Directory "/Users/myuser/dl_live">                <<< ----- this URL
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/dl.local_error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you do this you may see an error like this in your error log file:

```
[Tue Feb 03 13:50:26.189944 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 25254] [client 127.0.0.1:54841] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /Users/myUsername/path/to_local/virtual_host/
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved that problem by removing the standard virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf
And leaving only the virtual host configuration that you want.