# Access Forbidden Error 403 (XAMPP) (Mac)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

Need help setting up my virtual host to run PHP scripts and possibly Wordpress, I am getting the following error each time I try to open a PHP file. (no errors when running html, phpmyadmin etc).

I am using the following version of XAMPP.

```
v5.6.3 (PHP 5.6.3)
```

Error message

```
403 ACCESS FORBIDDEN
```

I have tried changing the configuration file to match the user account, re-installed xampp but nothing works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP (Mac) Virtual host showing 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365500/xampp-mac-virtual-host-showing-403)

Comment: Thank you, but I have already looked at the answers, tried all the solutions provided still no luck :(

Comment: Mmm, I'm not entirely too sure to be honest. I know it doesn't solve your problem, but have you tried MAMP?

Comment: I have tried MAMP, It works fine, but still looking for a solution for XAMPP :(

Comment: silly permissions issue.