# Access forbidden Error 403

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, htdocs

I am really close to having a meltdown here. 
I did a fresh install of XAMPP because of some trouble with starting MySQL database. The fresh install fixed that problem, but now I cant access localhost/project1.

The folder is placed in the htdocs folder and I just get the "Access forbidden!" message when I try to access it in my browser. 
I've spent 5 hours on this now and getting pretty pretty pretty desperate. All I want is to finish my assignment. 
Can anyone help me? Feels like I've tried EVERYTHING. Why is this even a problem?

Comment: Is there any `htaccess` file inside `localhost/project1`?

Comment: Have you made any changes to htaccess or your apache vhosts file?

Comment: Which OS you are using. If you are using Linux or Mac please check the permission for the project1 folder. Additionally you can check Apache's logs file fore more information if any error is there.

Comment: @ByteHamster No there is not any htaccess file inside my project folder

Comment: @iamgory Only changes I've done to the vhosts file is whats listed in the answer from User

Comment: @AlankarMore I am using osx. How can I check the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is also one way for rectifying **Access forbidden Error 403** .
Please Follow these steps.

**First Process:-**

**Step 1:-**

- Goto \XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file.
- And change this file as

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:8001>
>   ServerAdmin "webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com"
>   DocumentRoot "D:\XAMPP\htdocs\xyz"
>   ServerName "localhost:8001"
>   <Directory "D:\XAMPP\htdocs\xyz">
>          Allow from all
>   </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
>
> Note:-xyz is a project name.
> ```

**Step 2:-**

- Goto \XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf file and chenge

  **Listen 8001** and **ServerName localhost:8001**

Restart your xampp and i think now everything is fine.

> Note:-(Url:- localhost:8001/xyz)

**Second Process:-**

**Step 1:-**

- Change \XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf .
- In **New XAMPP security concept** of this code replace this below code

> ```
>  #
>  # New XAMPP security concept
>  # <LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))”>
>  Order deny,allow Allow from all Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
>  ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var </LocationMatch>
> ```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on a Mac. so I cant find "Listen 8001 and ServerName localhost:8001" in the httpd.conf file

Comment: I skipped the last step and no go:(

Comment: in the Second Process, are you talking about this: # New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

Comment: Just so I'm sure. you want me to replace whats inside <LocationMatch>   Require local
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var

Comment: please follow FirstProcess,if tried already plz change this line <Directory "D:\XAMPP\htdocs\xyz">
          Require all granted  </Directory>

Comment: have restart your xampp?

Comment: Yes. Do it between every change I make

Comment: ServerSignature Off
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks IncludesNoExec
        AllowOverride All

        #Order allow,deny  <- You can remove this
        #Allow from all    <- and that

        # Insert the following:
        Require all granted

Comment: For your reference plz take a look at this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365500/xampp-mac-virtual-host-showing-403\

Comment: Look at this link also  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33772/how-do-i-fix-the-error-403-i-am-getting-with-xampp-while-i-am-using-mod-userdir

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and go to htdocs folder or try below command

**$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/**

and then give 777 permission to your project folder:

**$ chmod 777 -R [foldername]**

It works for me, If you have any question, I will be happy to revert them.