# 403 forbidden opening form.php - Edited

Tags: php, xampp

I have a php file called form.php that contains :

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post" />
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and it is in XAMPP > htdocs > php and in the php folder it is as I said, form.php. Then I go into the browser and type http://localhost/php/form.php, and it says:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /php/form.php on this server.
>   Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I do not understand why it is saying that. I am on Mac OS X, if that helps.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

MAMP is a really good alternative for Mac users. It has Apache Server, and MySQL server.

Comment: Is there any .htaccess fiel in htdocs or php folder?

Comment: it means your apache is not able to read that file, so change the file permissions and ownership

Comment: There are a few threads on this topic already, have you seen them? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365500/xampp-mac-virtual-host-showing-403 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951499/mac-os-x-xampp-access-forbidden

Comment: +Feroz Akbar I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: I changed the permissions and it still doesn't work.